# Convert List to DataFrame after parsing from web

Tags: parsing, dataframe, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am a newbie with python. I want to recreate the table on CME website down below, however I am not able to convert the lists I have created to a data frame. any help much appreciated! Thanks in advance!

```
url = "http://www.cmegroup.com/trading/energy/crude-oil/light-sweet-crude_product_calendar_futures.html"
user_agent = 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.5; Windows NT)'
headers = { 'User-Agent' : user_agent }

req = urllib2.Request(url, headers=headers)

response = urllib2.urlopen(req)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response)

header = soup.findAll('th',limit = 8)
column_header = []
for j in header:
    column_header.append(j.getText())




data_rows = soup.findAll('tr')[2:]
dates = []
for i in range(len(data_rows)):
    for td in data_rows[i].findAll('td'):
        dates.append(td.getText())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

r = requests.get("http://www.cmegroup.com/trading/energy/crude-oil/light-sweet-crude_product_calendar_futures.html")

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "lxml")

headers = [th.text for th in soup.thead.find_all('th')]  # use thead to narrow the scope
print(headers)
for tr in soup.tbody.find_all('tr'):
    row = [i.get_text(strip=True) for i in tr(['th', 'td'])]
    print(row)
```

out:

```
['Contract Month', 'Product Code', 'First TradeLast Trade', 'Settlement', 'First HoldingLast Holding', 'First PositionLast Position', 'First NoticeLast Notice', 'First DeliveryLast Delivery']
['Feb 2017', 'CLG17', '21 Nov 201120 Jan 2017', '20 Jan 2017', '--', '23 Jan 201723 Jan 2017', '24 Jan 201724 Jan 2017', '01 Feb 201728 Feb 2017']
['Mar 2017', 'CLH17', '21 Nov 201121 Feb 2017', '21 Feb 2017', '--', '22 Feb 201722 Feb 2017', '23 Feb 201723 Feb 2017', '01 Mar 201731 Mar 2017']
['Apr 2017', 'CLJ17', '21 Nov 201121 Mar 2017', '21 Mar 2017', '--', '22 Mar 201722 Mar 2017', '23 Mar 201723 Mar 2017', '01 Apr 201730 Apr 2017']
['May 2017', 'CLK17', '21 Nov 201120 Apr 2017', '20 Apr 2017', '--', '21 Apr 201721 Apr 2017', '24 Apr 201724 Apr 2017', '01 May 201731 May 2017']
```

1. Use `.tbody` or `.thead` to narrow down the scope, do not use `limit`.
2. Use list comprehension to avoid use `append`

Comment: Thanks so much! (Y)

Comment: I actually found a way through it. Instead of bs4 I parsed with read_html by passing headers as the access was forbidden.